# How to create GridView Layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

I am trying to layout a 4x4 grid of tiles in flutter. I managed to do it with columns and rows. But now I found the `GridView` component. Could anyone provide an example on how to do it using it?

I can't really wrap my head around the docs. I don't seem to get the results I want.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

A simple example loading images into the tiles.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      color: Colors.white30,
      child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          children: <String>[
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
          ].map((String url) {
            return GridTile(
                child: Image.network(url, fit: BoxFit.cover));
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

The Flutter Gallery app contains a real world example, which can be found [here](https://flutter.github.io/samples/gallery.html).

[image]

Comment: How can i show the grid view in center if there are 8 items for example

Comment: please look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004532/index-flutter-grid-view

Answer (score 121):

Use whichever suits your need.

1. `GridView.count(...)`

   ```
   GridView.count(
     crossAxisCount: 2,
     children: <Widget>[
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. `GridView.builder(...)`

   ```
   GridView.builder(
     gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
     itemBuilder: (_, index) => FlutterLogo(),
     itemCount: 4,
   )
   ```
3. `GridView(...)`

   ```
   GridView(
     gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
     children: <Widget>[
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
     ],
   )
   ```
4. `GridView.custom(...)`

   ```
   GridView.custom(
     gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
     childrenDelegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
       [
         FlutterLogo(),
         FlutterLogo(),
         FlutterLogo(),
         FlutterLogo(),
       ],
     ),
   )
   ```
5. `GridView.extent(...)`

   ```
   GridView.extent(
     maxCrossAxisExtent: 400,
     children: <Widget>[
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
       FlutterLogo(),
     ],
   )
   ```

**Output (same for all):**

[image]

Comment: all solution in one post, thanks. how about different between them?

Comment: @DolDurma Thanks well there shouldn't be any such thing like "difference" between these widgets, they are meant to be used for different uses cases, so use the one which suits your need better.

Comment: Number 2 is a great option, thanks this post was very helpful

Comment: What is the significance of maxCrossAxisExtent ?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad whats different between `GridView.extent` and `GridView.custom`?

Comment: @DolDurma In `GridView.extent`, you specify `maxCrossAxisExtent` which tells children not to go over this width even if there's space available. In my example I used `400` which doesn't make much sense, go for some smaller value say `100` and you are forcing the children to stay `<=100` width individually.

Answer (score 43):

[`GridView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) is used for implementing material [grid lists](https://material.io/guidelines/components/grid-lists.html). If you know you have a fixed number of items and it's not very many (16 is fine), you can use `GridView.count`. However, you should note that a `GridView` is scrollable, and if that isn't what you want, you may be better off with just rows and columns.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Grid Demo'),
      ),
      body: new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        children: new List<Widget>.generate(16, (index) {
          return new GridTile(
            child: new Card(
              color: Colors.blue.shade200,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text('tile $index'),
              )
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i show the grid view in center if there are 8 items for example

Answer (score 27):

Please visit this [repo](https://github.com/flutter-devs/flutter_gridview_demo).

```
Widget _gridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 9.0,
      children: itemList
          .map(
            (Item) => ItemList(item: Item),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
```

Below screenshot contains **crossAxisCount: 2**
[image: this screenshot is for grid count 2]

Comment: How this childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 9.0 is calculated ? What's the process behind finding 8.0/9.0 ??

Comment: please look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004532/index-flutter-grid-view

Comment: the link above is dead

Answer (score 18):

There are few named constructors in `GridView` for different scenarios,

**Constructors**

1. `GridView`
2. `GridView.builder`
3. `GridView.count`
4. `GridView.custom`
5. `GridView.extent`

Below is a example of `GridView` constructor:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: ExampleGrid(),
  ),
);

class ExampleGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> images = [
    "https://uae.microless.com/cdn/no_image.jpg",
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81aF3Ob-2KL._UX679_.jpg",
    "https://www.boostmobile.com/content/dam/boostmobile/en/products/phones/apple/iphone-7/silver/device-front.png.transform/pdpCarousel/image.jpg",
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgUgs8_kmuhScsx-J01d8fA1mhlCR5-1jyvMYxqCB8h3LCqcgl9Q",
    "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB11tA5aiAKL1JjSZFoq6ygCFXaw/Unlocked-Samsung-GALAXY-S2-I9100-Mobile-Phone-Android-Wi-Fi-GPS-8-0MP-camera-Core-4.jpg_640x640.jpg",
    "https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com/gmc/sierra-3500hd/2018/td/2018_gmc_sierra-3500hd_f34_td_411183_1600.jpg",
    "https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/16q1/665019/2016-chevrolet-silverado-2500hd-high-country-diesel-test-review-car-and-driver-photo-665520-s-original.jpg",
    "https://www.galeanasvandykedodge.net/assets/stock/ColorMatched_01/White/640/cc_2018DOV170002_01_640/cc_2018DOV170002_01_640_PSC.jpg",
    "https://media.onthemarket.com/properties/6191869/797156548/composite.jpg",
    "https://media.onthemarket.com/properties/6191840/797152761/composite.jpg",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(), // if you want IOS bouncing effect, otherwise remove this line
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),//change the number as you want
        children: images.map((url) {
          return Card(child: Image.network(url));
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want your GridView items to be dynamic according to the content, you can few lines to do that but the simplest way to use `StaggeredGridView` package. I have provided an answer with example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781657/adjust-gridview-child-height-according-to-the-dynamic-content-in-flutter/54059209#54059209).

Below is an example for a `GridView.count`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: ExampleGrid(),
      ),
    );

class ExampleGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        children: List.generate(40, (index) {
          return Card(
            child: Image.network("https://robohash.org/$index"),
          ); //robohash.org api provide you different images for any number you are giving
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot for above snippet:

[image: Flutter gridview example by blasanka using card widget and robohash api]

Example for a `SliverGridView`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: ExampleGrid(),
      ),
    );

class ExampleGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        primary: false,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            sliver: SliverGrid.count(
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: List.generate(20, (index) {
                return Card(child: Image.network("https://robohash.org/$index"));
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004532/index-flutter-grid-view

Comment: thank, physics: BouncingScrollPhysics() is necesary for android too