# How do I create a dynamic flutter grid layout based on device orientation when the items have dynamic height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a layout similar to Android's build in Contacts App, when creating a new contact (or editing one for that matter), in portrait mode the whole view is scroll-able with the user's avatar placed on top of the contact form in a top-to-bottom layout, when you switch to landscape mode however, the layout changes to a side-by-side layout with the avatar taking up the left half of the screen (full height and non scroll-able) and the contact form to the right fully scroll-able independent of the avatar to the left which stays fixed.

I tried implementing this using the flutter_staggered_grid_view library by setting the `crossAxisCount` in a `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder` based on the device orientation this will make it so that I can switch between having only 1 item in the cross axis (in portrait mode where there's a vertical layout) to having 2 items in the cross axis (in landscape mode where there's a horizontal layout).

Unfortunately, even though the `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder` is nested within a `OrientationBuilder` whenever I switch orientation, the layout doesn't seem to update as if the `crossAxisCount` property is not dynamic and can not be updated once set.

```
body: OrientationBuilder(
    builder: (context, or) {
        int cac = (or == Orientation.portrait) ? 1 : 2;
            return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                controller: _listViewScrollController,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return _view[index];
                },
                itemCount: 2,
                crossAxisCount: cac,
                staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
                    return StaggeredTile.fit(cac);
                },
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            );
        },
    )
```

There's the possibility that Grids aren't the right approach to creating such a layout, if that's the case, I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if anyone want to get different size GridView according to image sizes, read this SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781657/adjust-gridview-child-height-according-to-the-dynamic-content-in-flutter/54059209#54059209

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a better approach would be to play with `Row`, `Column` and `SingleChildScrollView`:

You can try something like this:

```
Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildAvatar(context, orientation),
              _buildFields(context),
            ],
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildAvatar(context, orientation),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: _buildFields(context),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _buildAvatar(BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
    return Container(
      height: 300.0,
      width: orientation == Orientation.landscape ? 300.0 : null,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text('RR'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFields(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 800.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 250.0,
          width: 250.0,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: contact layout]

The `buildBody` function will create the layout above, and you'll have to replace the content of `_buildAvatar` and `_buildFields` to fit your needs.

Comment: This is a layout I've already tried, but because on orientation change the form is rebuilt, and data in the fields are being reset. Would a TextEditController keep the form data persisted after a rebuild?

Comment: Oh ok, this is off topic for this question and you may need to post another question for that if you want a detailed solution. But yes you have to create TextEditControllers to keep the data inside your `State`.