# Flutter row overflfow with list

Tags: flutter

I have a list I'm mapping:

```
List<Widget> names = post.names
          .map(
            (c) => new Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: new Text('' + c['name']),
                ),
          )
          .toList();
```

And displaying:

```
new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: names,
          ),
```

However, the row overflows to right if it has too many items in it. I tried to wrap it to Expanded / Flexible widgets, but that causes error about the parent widget not having height.

If I try to use:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
```

I get:

```
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
```

I also tried to use Expanded inside the Row, however that is not possible as I'm creating the children from the list and that causes error.

How to achieve a name list which also expands vertically based to amount of items?

Comment: Did you try `Wrap` instead of `Row`?

Comment: Thanks! Wrap did the trick. Didn't even know that Widget existed. Drop it as an answer and I'm more than happy to accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Wrap` instead of `Row` like this.

```
Wrap(
  children: names,
  //...
),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the widgets to be scrollable horizontally, use a list view and set the axis to horizontal.

But if you want the widgets to wrap, then you need to build a grid instead of a row.

Check out this post: [Flutter - Layout a Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183795/flutter-layout-a-grid)

Comment: Wrap was the way to go, thaanks to @CopsOnRoad got it to work by simply swapping Row to Wrap. Thanks for the reply anyways!