# Flutter GridView.count in Row Layout Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm new in flutter and i want to draw a image grid in a row. i used this example [Flutter - Layout a Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183795/flutter-layout-a-grid) but it show me every time a error

```
Widget buildView(){
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child:
      new Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: new GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                      children: <String>[
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/150',

                      ].map((String url) {
                        return new GridTile(
                            child: new Image.network(url, fit: BoxFit.cover));
                      }).toList()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

i becode every time this error "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to wrap GridView in a Row unless you are trying to divide the row. You can just use GridView.

```
new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          children: <String>[
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150',

          ].map((String url) {
            return new GridTile(
                child: new Image.network(url, fit: BoxFit.cover));
          }).toList()),
```

If you really want to wrap it inside a row you need wrap GridView with a container and define a width or wrap in a flexible

```
Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: new GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                children: <String>[
                  'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                  'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                  'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                  'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                  'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                  'https://via.placeholder.com/150',    

                ].map((String url) {
                  return new GridTile(
                      child: new Image.network(url, fit: BoxFit.cover));
                }).toList()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

If you get unbounded height error just wrap it with a container or sizedbox and define a height

Comment: i tried the both methods but the i become the same error

Comment: i forgot to say i have this element in a padding element. i think this occurs the error. any idea how i can solve this ?

Comment: I think the error is not with this part of code.. Seems its from parent.. Just try my example as the body of a scaffold you'll see its working.. If you could show the parent of this code it'll be useful

Comment: just remove column, row and flexible

Comment: any other options ?

Comment: there's no use of wrapping it in rows and columns unnecessarily bro, GridView does this for you..  you can set mainAxisSize: min for the column