# Flutter Grid Layout: how to implement this layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need help on how to implement this asymmetrical grid where all the tiles are the same size

Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183795/flutter-layout-a-grid

Answer (score 0):

This is just a very simple example of a grid of numbers

```
GridView(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,

          childAspectRatio: 2 / 1, //ratio cells width to cells height
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: numbers
            .map(
              (number) => Text(number.toString()),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
```

if you need more explanation let me know

Comment: is this what you wanted?