# How to make multiple Cupertino buttons in SafeArea in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I am creating a flutter app which has a gridview of Cupertino buttons which are all gonna be clickable and when clicked pass on to a new page.
I have managed to create one Cupertino button with the help of this article -
https://medium.com/@zhijjjj/flutter-ios-style-clickable-card-35aa151a6116
I want to make many more buttons, but I am unable to work out the way. Please can someone help me?

Comment: Use a listview or gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `GridView` in a flutter

How to use GridView? [Here are many examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183795/flutter-layout-a-grid) how to use it

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      color: Colors.white30,
      child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          children: <String>[
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
            'http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png',
          ].map((String url) {
            return GridTile(
                child: Image.network(url, fit: BoxFit.cover));
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Asked

> if I want multiple cards with different images in the background and
> different text on top of it, can it be possible?

Then you can use `flutter_staggered_grid_view` plugin you can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

```
new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this, but if I want multiple cards with different images in the background and different text on top of it, can it be possible?