# How to get this type of card with column and Row combinations?

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter. can anyone help me out to get this type of card with column and Row combinations. Please help.
[image: picture]

Comment: Try out with flutter grid layout -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183795/flutter-layout-a-grid

Answer (score 2):

I made you a demo, i hope it is going to help you. I also write some comment to you in the code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.orange[100], // background color
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 20.0),
              child: Text("All rooms", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900], fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 32, // minus 32 due to the margin
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow[100], // background color of the cards
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        // this is the shadow of the card
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // posion the everything to the bottom
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // place here your image
                        Text("Bed room", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.brown, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text("4 Lights", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.orange)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 32, // minus 32 due to the margin
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow[100], // background color of the cards
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        // this is the shadow of the card
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // posion the everything to the bottom
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // place here your image
                        Text("Living room", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.brown, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text("2 Lights", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.orange)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 32, // minus 32 due to the margin
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow[100], // background color of the cards
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        // this is the shadow of the card
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // posion the everything to the bottom
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // place here your image
                        Text("Kitchen", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.brown, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text("5 Lights", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.orange)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 32, // minus 32 due to the margin
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow[100], // background color of the cards
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        // this is the shadow of the card
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // posion the everything to the bottom
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // place here your image
                        Text("Bathroom", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.brown, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text("1 Lights", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.orange)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 32, // minus 32 due to the margin
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow[100], // background color of the cards
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        // this is the shadow of the card
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // posion the everything to the bottom
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // place here your image
                        Text("Bed room", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.brown, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text("4 Lights", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.orange)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 32, // minus 32 due to the margin
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow[100], // background color of the cards
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        // this is the shadow of the card
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // posion the everything to the bottom
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // place here your image
                        Text("Living room", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.brown, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text("2 Lights", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.orange)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I think this type of combination is best when we implement it dynamically. Otherwise, we get headache for this long repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below widget:

```
class MyCardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  String title;
  String description;
  IconData iconData;
  
  
  MyCardItem(this.title, this.description, this.iconData);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
      elevation: 3,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Icon(iconData, size:30),
          Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color:Colors.brown),),
          Text(description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then use it as follow:

```
MyCardItem("Bed room", "4 lights", Icons.done)
```

feel free to replace Icon with Image!